# Unable to modify an item in a larger dataset

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, hdf5, h5py

My dataset consists of a multidimensional array of matrices. I am trying to change the value of one of the matrices but the code I have written keeps showing the old value even after I have reassigned the new value:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

f1 = h5py.File('myfile.h5', 'r+')
print("Keys: %s" % f1.keys())
print("old value is :", f1["myArray"][0][0][0])
f1["myArray"][0][0][0] = 100
f1.close()

f2 = h5py.File('myfile.h5', 'r')
print("Keys: %s" % f2.keys())
print("new value is :", f2["myArray"][0][0][0])
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in how you index. To do what you want, you will want to write to the item `[0,0,0]` (and not `[0][0][0]`). The following code does what you intended:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

file = h5py.File('myfile.h5', 'w')

file["myArray"] = np.arange(5*5*5).reshape(5,5,5)
print("old value is :", file["myArray"][0,0,0])

file["myArray"][0,0,0] = 100
print("new value is :", file["myArray"][0,0,0])

file.close()
```

(Also work when you close/reopen the file, which I omitted for clarity). This code outputs:

```
old value is : 0
new value is : 100
```

Please consider [Numpy's documentation on indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) to get more information.

---

After reading the documentation it should surprise you, that what you did did not work. Because

```
A = np.arange(5*5*5).reshape(5,5,5)
A[0][0][0] = 100
print(A[0,0,0])
```

does output `100`. This works because each time you do `[0]` you get a pointer to a sub-array (and not a copy). Modifying entries of this sub-array thus modifies the underlying data (the original array).

My guess is that because `h5py` writes to the disc, taking `[0]` for the first time *does return a copy* (while thereafter a pointer is returned). This suspicion is confirmed in this example:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

file = h5py.File('myfile.h5', 'w')
file["myArray"] = np.arange(5*5*5).reshape(5,5,5)

data = file["myArray"][0]
data[0,0] = 100
print(data[0,0])
print(file["myArray"][0,0,0])

file.close()
```

which outputs

```
100
0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.